# gRPC: Role of the ClientAsyncStreamingInterface.Finish() and the CompleitionQueue

Tags: grpc

I'm trying to understand the [greeter_async_client.cc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.15.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc) from the helloworld example of the gRPC [docs](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html).

With respect to line 76:
`rpc->Finish(&reply, &status, (void*)1);`

The api [reference](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1internal_1_1_client_async_streaming_interface.html#ad83ce06905fe819ae1e6b5b85e437642) mentions that the `ClientAsyncStreamingInterface::Finish()` function will return if:

> This function will return when either:
>
> - **all incoming messages have been read and the server has returned a status.**
> - the server has returned a non-OK status.
> - the call failed for some reason and the library generated a status.

Does this mean that `Finish()` is blocking? And if it is, then what is the role of the `CompletionQueue`. Can't we just read the response once the `Finish()` call returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is incorrect and outdated. Please refer to the latest documentation. In short, Finish() is not blocking and it always returns immediately. 'This function will return' should be replaced with 'The tag will be returned'.

Comment: Where can I find the latest documentation? I found this here: https://grpc.io/docs/reference/

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/b558519d999f699b93f09a960d31438dae3666a8/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h#L79 This would be the latest documentation